# Display image from external source in View in Play 2.5 framework

Tags: playframework

I have been trying to develop a Play 2.5 app to display instagram pictures by taking hashtag as input and calling the instagram rest API and displaying the result.I plan to deploy the app on Heroku which uses Postgres database.
Inorder to display the images,I plan to just use the URL string in the image tag in the View, `<img src=@collection.img/>`
But when i run the app locally, the image is not displayed and localhost is getting attached to src attribute.

```
src = http://localhost:9000/%22https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/10296636_1024245191001256_1641267310_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTIwODg5NTI5ODg4NDk5NDk1Ng%3D%3D.2%22/
```

1.I tried to install the CORS plugin and allow https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/* urls to pass.

2.I tried changing option of cors in application.conf:-

```
cors {
# Filter paths by a whitelist of path prefixes
#pathPrefixes = ["/some/path", ...]

# The allowed origins. If null, all origins are allowed.
allowedOrigins = [".instagram.com", "localhost:9000",".cdninstagram.com"]

# The allowed HTTP methods. If null, all methods are allowed
allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST"]
} 

hosts {
# Allow requests to example.com, its subdomains, and localhost:9000.
allowed = [".instagram.com", "localhost:9000",".cdninstagram.com"]
}
```

This is my controller where I am calling the Instagram API:

```
Collection collection = formFactory.form(Collection.class).bindFromRequest().get();
    Collection cocoTasks = Collection.find.where()
            .ilike("name",collection.name)
            .findUnique();
   Node res = printCollection(cocoTasks);
    for(JsonNode coll : res) {
        ResultCollection c1 = new ResultCollection();
        c1.setcName(collection.name);
        c1.setURLName(coll.get("link").toString());
        c1.setImg(coll.get("images").get("standard_resolution").get("url").toString());
        c1.setInstagramUsername(coll.get("user").get("username").toString());
        c1.save();



@Transactional
public JsonNode printCollection(Collection c) throws InterruptedException,ExecutionException{

    CompletionStage<JsonNode> json = getCollectionHelper(c);
    CompletableFuture<JsonNode> res1 =json.toCompletableFuture();
    JsonNode jArray = res1.get();
    JsonNode res2 = jArray.get("data");
return res2;
}

 @Inject WSClient ws;
public CompletionStage<JsonNode> getCollectionHelper(Collection c) {


    String feedUrl = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/"+c.hashTag+"/media/recent?access_token=my_access_token";
    WSRequest request = ws.url(feedUrl);


    CompletionStage<JsonNode> output = request
            .setRequestTimeout(-1).setQueryParameter("count","20").get()
            .thenApply(response -> response.asJson());

    return output;

}
```

Here is my Collection model class:

```
public class Collection extends Model{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public String id;

public String name;

public String hashTag;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public String getHashTag() {
    return hashTag;
}

public void setHashTag(String hashTag) {
    this.hashTag = hashTag;
}
public static Finder<String, Collection> find = new Finder<String,Collection>(Collection.class);

}
```

None of these settings seems to work. I can stream the image and store it in the local database, but would not prefer the option unless absolutely necessary.
Is there something I am missing?
Thanks.

Comment: Which CORS plugin? Also, try `<img src="@collection.img" />`. Notice the double quotes.

Comment: I did try with quotes, but the URL is still appending localhost to the URL.I am using Allow-Control-Allow-Origin:* offered by vitvad on Chrome.

Comment: You will have to show us the code that retrieve the urls from Instagram.

Comment: I have added the code,Thanks.